# What is the effect on battery life of enabling glonass support on garmin edge 25?

Tags: gps, garmin

I'm considering the purchase of a new GPS. The Garmin Edge 25 has most of the basic features I need. However, high accuracy is important to me as I do trail mapping for my local MTB club. I thought that getting a unit with GLONASS support would help improve accuracy, but I was concerned about runtime since the manual indicates it will reduce battery life.

What is the impact on battery life of enabling GLONASS support on the Garmin Edge 25?

Comment: Are you sure this question might not be better suited for something like: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com since it is clearly not about bicycles?

Comment: or even, ask Garmin directly, or visit the Garmin user forums? I must admit I've found their tech support a bit useless, but I've had some success asking about my 800 on their forums

Comment: @renesis the Edge 25 is a bicycle-specific device.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with garmin devices, but I do run a super cheap/nasty cellphone with strava, and a gopro off a 10Ah USB battery.  The cellphone normally gets ~4 hours and the gopro only got ~2 hours before they're flat, and with the USB battery I can run both for 12+ hours.   I fit the phone and battery in a top-tube bag, and run a short USB cable to the gopro on the headtube.  Works for me, and its much more flexible.    Can the garmin run while being charged by USB?

Comment: Can the garmin run while being charged by USB? - I don't know if It can be run while charging. However, it does require a special dock, so it likely can't be mounted and charging at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

You're only going to experience roughly a 10%, (maybe 20% max) loss of battery life. Unless you're planning on frequent century or all-day rides, the difference is relatively negligible. The average use case, a commute to and from work, or the average 4 hour group ride, won't see any difference because the battery life will go from about 8 hours on a full charge to 7 hours.

If you *do* plan to take it on century rides or night rides, you might want to upgrade to a medium tier unit, 510/520/etc, as the medium sized units have nearly twice the battery life. Using the GPS+GLONASS mode doesn't have a significant effect on battery life at all in this case because we're looking at about 16 hours of battery life in GPS-only mode vs 15 hours of battery life with GLONASS. Unless you're living on the edge (no pun intended), the GLONASS mode isn't going to make it or break it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I always leave my Edge 520 in GPS+GLONASS mode and I've never used more than about 60% of the battery in a single day.

Comment: I have an Edge 510 which has GPS & Glonass. I would support the estimate of  20% reduction in battery life when Glonass is enabled. The accuracy and reliability is much better though, if you are in forested areas.

Answer (score 2):

I can share my experience with the unit. I love it for it's simplicity, but the battery life is becoming an issue after only a few months use. Yesterday we went out on a slow welcome back ride. 5 miles to the meetup point, 40 miles with a cake stop in the middle, then 5 miles home. I charged the unit overnight. Set out at 9:30 AM. Ran out of battery at 14:20 ish while we were chatting at the meetup point before heading home.
I have GPS and GLONASS switched on.
I'm planning longer rides this year, and hopefully me first hundred. I reckon I'll be averaging 13mph so I'll need the battery to last for 8 hours just with on the move time, without factoring in breaks, so I'm already looking at ways to extend the battery life, or upgrading within a year of purchase.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Adrian. Thanks for answering one of our questions. As with all new members we recommend taking the [tour] to make best use of the site.

Comment: Did you find a solution @Adrian?  I'm having the same issues - it used to last 8 hours when I bought it, but now 6 months later it's only doing 5ish.